# WPF user control running storyboard against parent window object

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I have a UserControl contained within a parent window in WPF. The usercontrol contains a button that when pressed, needs to call back to the parent window and start a storyboard animation to set the opacity of the UserControl to 0, while setting the opacity of a different UserControl to 1.

So effectively there is a button within my usercontrol that hides the containing usercontrol and switches to another one being visible.

If the button is in the main window, it is easy as the first user control has an x:Name of leftpanel and the second is called leftpanelexpanded.

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Leftpanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0"/>
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Leftpanelexpanded" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="1"/>
```

But with the button in the user control, I can't figure out how to have this animation target the "leftpanel" and "leftpanelexpanded" usercontrol objects. I have tried RelativeSource but I can only get a handle to the parent window this way, I cant get a handle to the user control contained within the parent window.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well multiple ways you can address this:

1. Have a custom [Dependency Property](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html#creation) in the `UserControl` that is say of type `bool`. On your `Button` click inside the `UserControl` set this bool DP to true. In the parent `Window`, use a `` `Trigger `` to check this DP and when `True` use a `BeginStoryboard` action to start the `Storyboard`.
2. Repeat same process as above but use the `Tag` property instead of a custom DP. (Try to avoid this method. Just ain't too nice)
3. Create a custom `RoutedEvent` in your `UserControl` and fire the event from the `Button.Click`. Have the parent Window subscribe to this event and invoke the Storyboard.
4. If your using something like a `Messenger` / `EventAggregator` class, just send a message across to the parent View from the `Button.Click` and invoke the Storyboard from the parent View when receiving this message.
5. Create an `ICommand` property in your parent-view and have your `Button` in the `UserControl` bind to this Command via a `RelativeSource` binding or if it's `DataContext` is the parent Window, you wouldn't even need a `RelativeSource` to access the command. In the Command's `OnExecute(...)` start the Storyboard.

**Summary:**

I bet there are quite a few more options I can't think of quickly, crux is when your `Button.Click` occurs inform the parent in your manner of choosing that **it** needs to change the state of it's children however it chooses to do so and give the responsibility of actioning that request to the parent View.

The child stops at the point of requesting a state change, the parent View is the one that actually does it. This saves you all the access to control's problem and also helps stay true to the principle of "Have one thing worry about that thing and that thing only"(the "thing" being each view's class here)